# How to detect save and tab change event using angular8 with bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, angular

i have used bootstrap4 tabs in angular8. Now if i have not filled details in first tab, (i.e) `user` tab and click on submit, then the `other` tab must be disabled, once the submit button is click then the other tab must be enabled.
Here based on click of other tab, the contents in the `other` tab must be loaded, if `other` tab is not clicked, then the details in `others` tab must not be filled. I have tried by using click event and tabChange event, but everything works in app.component but the data doesnt come to the user or other tab based on click on other tab.

I am not getting anyway to move forward, i have even used event emitters and storage inside the app, through service files, but nothing worked for me.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ygga4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your Demo and I think I understand your problem. I personally am a fan of using ReplaySubjects, and EventEmitters to pass data up and down through my components. Here is a working demo : 
 [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-4mdzvp) 
Let me know if it is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for response, here on click of Others tab, i want the data to be loaded in the others tab, if i have not clicked on others tab, the data should be empty

Comment: i have used your answer and forked an example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-f12stw?file=src/app/other-table/other-table.component.ts. Here based on click of others tab, data must be loaded. If i have not clicked on others tab, then the data in others tab must not be loaded, here based on click of others tab, i will load the api required to that screen

Comment: and here based on click of others tab, if i am adding new entries then i need to fetch id from localstorage from the browser, this can be handled?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-ygga4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts

Comment: could you please help me to throw validation message, when the form is dirty and i click on other tab, if i say no, then it must go to other tab, if i click on yes, it must retain in the same tab

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-vwwtti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.html, in this demo, i had made data to show only in click of other tab, now, if the form is dirty in user tab and click on other tab, alert message should throw, if yes it must remain in same screen but if i say no, then it must go to next screen, could you please put console and help me out, what should be condition for yes if form is dity and no if i dont want to save changes and move to other tab

Comment: Hey sorry for the long response, here is a working example of what I think you want. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-foykqe). You can use another EventEmitter to track if you form is valid ('aka Dirty'), and ngClass to disable and enable your tab button.  [Link to Ng Class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) [Link to FormGroup] (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

Comment: thanks for response, but it is not working as i expected

Comment: here, if i make the form as dirty in usertab and before click of button, if i go to others tab then validation error must popup

Comment: here you are checking for status as valid or not, like that i need to check for form dirty, and i have totally 11 tabs, like this tabs i can handle for each and everything na?

Comment: if the userForm is not dirty, then it must allow user to go to other tab, if the userForm is dirty then it must throw validation error.

Comment: Ah, there are a few ways you could approach this then. But if you have 11 tabs I would create a ReplaySubject in your controller to track when the user changes tabs, that way you can subscribe in individual components and popup errors where needed.

Comment: Thanks but could you please help me out to throw validation message if the fork is dirty in user tab and I am trying to go for others tab

Comment: have you got time to go through my issue and doubts?